# reading and manipulating a textfile with HTTPGET

Tags: c#, integration-testing, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API controller that is getting a string uri and manipulating it as follows :-

```
    [HttpGet("/api/TextFileAPI/Get/")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Get(string uri)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        var stringTask = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

        return Json(stringTask);
    }
```

Now I am trying to create a test for this, to ensure that I get a 200 reply and that everything is working fine, however I cannot seem to be able to pass the URL correctly.  My code at present is as follows:-

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Get_EnsureSuccessStatusCode_TextFileAPIController()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/download/text/textfile1.txt");

        var response = await _client.GetAsync(_request + "Get/" + uri);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
```

which is returning a 404 not found.  If I change the URI to a normal string, I manage to get into my controller, so it looks like the formatting of the uri is not correct.

Anyone has any idea on how I can pass the URI correctly?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: What is the value of `_request`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `uri` value as a query string parameter instead of appending it to the path.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/download/text/textfile1.txt");
var response = await _client.GetAsync(_request + "Get?uri=" + uri);
```

The reason why you have to pass it as a query string parameter is because `uri` is not part of the route. If you want to keep passing `uri` as a path segment, you must add it to your route. Otherwise, your URL will not match any routes. That explains where the 404 Not Found comes from.

```
// matches /api/TextFileAPI/Get/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fdownload%2Ftext%2Ftextfile1.txt
[HttpGet("/api/TextFileAPI/Get/{uri}")]
```

With this approach, you must ensure that any forward slashes in the `{uri}` path segment are URL encoded.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/download/text/textfile1.txt");
var response = await _client.GetAsync(_request + "Get/" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(uri.ToString()));
```

Comment: No problem. I added some more useful information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks for your help and time!